# PlayStation4 From Hong Hong to INDIA

Tags: india, hong-kong

Am planning to buy PS4 from Hong Kong and about to return India, do they charge custom duty tax for that once i arrive in india?

Please reply

Answer (score -1):

Reading through the actual [CBEC documentation](http://www.cbec.gov.in/excise/cxt2013-14/chap85.pdf) (trigger warning: PDF), it looks like you could be liable for 12%, though there doesn't appear to be a specific tariff listed for computers or consoles (that I can find).

Non-electrical toys (chapter 95) also seem to be taxed evenly at 12%.

Comment: Incorrect.  As a traveller, you can import items worth up to Rs.35,000 duty free.

Comment: Right, and the local price of a PS4? Over Rs. 35k

Comment: What matters is the purchase price in Hong Kong, not in India.  Random Googling digs up 2,943 HKD, or ~23300 INR.